# How to make dynamic article suggestion in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have Articles in my application.

And I want to show some suggestion articles inside of article text

For this I define a short code in text section when I am creating a article like `[short_article id = 1]` and in controller I search for this short code and replace it with this code :

```
$content = preg_replace('/\[short_article id=(\d+)]/i' , 
          '<a href="http://localhost:8000/articles/${1}">Suggestion article</a>' , 
          $article->text);
```

As you can see I can get entered id when I am creating a article and use it in link,
But I don't have access to article with entered id and I can't put title in tag `a`

How can I get article with entered id ??

Comment: What does the suggestion stand for?

Comment: @MahdiJedari it's refrence to other article who we entered id

Comment: I didn't get your meaning but I suggest you fetch your suggested articles in the model and attach them as a relation on that. So you can have access where ever you want.